# How to permanently add font to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uifont

I have some nice fonts that I like to use in my iOS applications. However, it is slightly annoying to add the font to Xcode every time. Is there a way I can keep add a font permanently to a project so it will stay in there forever? Please let me know if I am not being specific enough. Thanks!

Comment: you need to add them per project If they are not one of the standard iOS system fonts.

Comment: What do you mean "add a font permanently to a project"? You only have to add a font once to a project and it will stay until you delete it from the project.

Comment: I mean for it to be saved into Xcode. I can add fonts into each separate project, but I prevent having to add it each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately only standard iOS fonts are "permanently" in Xcode. Other fonts have to be added in manually when you want to use it in a specific project.

This is because when you add the font it is included in your bundle when uploaded to the app store vs. the system fonts already being on the iOS system.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help!